# Is PyGObject a good replacement for Tk on both Windows and Linux?

Tags: python, windows, gtk3, ubuntu-18.04

Python 3.5.4, 
Windows 7, 
Ubuntu Mate 18.04

We have 7-8 Python 3 based projects that are built to use both Windows 7 and Ubuntu Mate platforms. Most of the development is done on Windows using LiClipse and the user interface is tk. This has worked very well but we were trying to improve the interface look so we are attempting to use GTK+ 3. There have been numerous hours spent trying to get LiClipse to recognize the gi.repository(No module named 'gi'): [image: LiClipse error]

The GTK website mentions both vcpkg and MSYS2 installation methods. 
[GTK Download for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php)

We installed and built GTK3 based on the vcpkg instructions only to realize that we would need to develop the code in Microsoft Visual Studio. I hesitate to go down the MSYS2 road as I'm not sure if this will allow Windows 7 development(with LiClipse) and deployment.

The second avenue looked at was something that was part of the pip ecosystem. Using pip to install packages for development and deployment has been extremely easy. The PyGObject seems to fit, but we are having issues installing pycario("Running setup.py install for pycairo: finished with status 'error'").

Because of the issues so far, we wanted to ask if we are proceeding down a road that will lead to a good solution. If we can get pip to install PyGObject, is it a good GTK+ 3 multiplatform replacement for tk ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking for a good cross platform GUI toolkit, have a look at [Qt for Python](https://www.qt.io/qt-for-python).

Comment: We looked at using a normal Qt development environment a couple years back but ran into a lot of serial port issues(which is how we ended up coding the projects in Python.) Are you forced to used the Qt IDE if you want to use Qt for Python?

Comment: Yep I remember a lot of trouble with the QtSerialPort part as well, but it's completely unrelated to the rest of the framework, especially the GUI part. As for the question, no, you can use whatever you want; it's "regular" Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed some projects for Windows and Linux using Gtk3 and I have to say it is really good. For my projects, coded in C++, I have used MSYS2. vcpkg works great too, but aims primarily at Visual Studio users. I would advice vcpkg for coding in C or C++.

> I hesitate to go down the MSYS2 road as I'm not sure if this will
>   allow Windows 7 development(with LiClipse) and deployment.

You should really try MSYS2. It has support for everything you need (even pip).

Comment: So do you use an Eclipse based IDE on the Windows platform for developing? I'm just trying to verify that using MSYS2 method of Gtk3 installation will allow me to continue to develop in LiClipse.

Comment: I don't know much about liclipse, but it should be possible to integrate it with MSYS2. Much probably you only need to prepend C:\msys64\mingw64\bin; to the PATH environment variable, so that liclipse launches the MSYS2 python.exe binary. Look for a project option to set the python executable or the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any problem! As for installing PyGObject in MSYS2 there are instructions here: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html (but probably you already know how to do that)

Comment: I'm definitely a little confused about the dependencies of PyGObject. The PyGOobject website uses a MSYS2 install and then you install PyGOobject into the mingw64 environment: [PyGObject](pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) If you then look at the PyPi website for installing the PyGObject simply uses pip: [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/PyGObject/) Is MSYS2 a requirement for PyGObject on Windows or simply the preferred installation?

Comment: On MSYS2 you can install PyGObject either using the mingw-w64-python3-gobject pacman package, or through pip3. Both ways work, but I prefer to use the pacman package. This is the same as on Linux, where some Python libraries are present both as system packages or as pip packages, and the user has freedom to choose which package manager to use. For the final question, yes, MSYS2 is not strictly a requirement for PyGObject, but it's by far the preferred installation.

Comment: It seems that your MSYS2 recommendation is the only way to currently get Gtk3 to work on Windows for a novice Python user. I've been unable to get PyGObject to install using pip in a Windows command shell and have run out of time trying to get it to work. Thanks for all the information/insight.